# Assigning two IPs to one NIC in CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, nic, ipv4

I have been following this method described here:

http://linuxwave.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-virtual-ip-in-centos.html

To assign a virtual IP to one NIC.

Basically I copied ifcfg-eth0 and makde it ifcfg-eth0:1, set a new device name and IP Address, but the error I get when I do

> service network restart

is as such:

> Active connection state : activated
>   Active conncetion path : /org/ freedesktop /NetworkManager /ActiveConnection/xx

The actual config for ifcfg-eth0:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.1.10.10
PREFIX=23
GATEWAY=10.1.10.1
DNS1=10.1.10.1
DOMAIN=company.com
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
UUID=xyz
HWADDR=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
```

Actual config for ifcfg-eth0:1

```
DEVICE="eth0:1"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.1.10.2
PREFIX=23
GATEWAY=10.1.10.11
DNS1=10.1.10.1
DOMAIN=company.com
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0:1"
UUID=xyz
HWADDR=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE
```

Where xx is a number that increases each time I restart the network. Then only one IP address shows up when I do ifconfig... How do I solve this problem?

The multiple IP is used for creating a virtual host with apache.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The secondary IP should have a prefix of 32 and no gateway or dns. It certainly should not have a `DEFROUTE=yes` either.

Comment: Same problem, I stripped down ifcfg-eth0:1 to only have: Device, onboot, bootproto, IPaddr, prefix. Still get the same error, and typing ifconfig doesn't show the secondary IP. Does it matter I have the GNOME desktop installed? Is the network manager UI interfering?

Comment: Most likely a Network Manager issue - uninstall it. (I always do)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks Cole! I just stopped the NetworkManager: service NetworkManager stop, and chkconfig NetworkManager off, and then did a 'service network restart' and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Shiroi98: Make sure you have 'network' start to start automatically, otherwise if you reboot you'll have no networking.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also set `NM_CONTROLLED="no"` instead of stopping NetworkManger service, so you won't have issue on reboots.