# CentOS 6.3 - Add IP's To Eth0?

Tags: centos, ipv4

How would I go about adding 3 IP's to my eth0.

When I tried the following, the whole network crashed.

```
ifconfig eth0 192.95.22.105 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 198.27.64.254
```

How would I go about adding more IP's to my CentOS server?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/472575/assigning-two-ips-to-one-nic-in-centos ?

Comment: No, this seems a valid question of someone who thinks ifconfig *adds* addresses to an interface instead of *replacing* the current config...

Answer (score 4):

when you issued this command you overwritten your actual interface configuration.

There are two ways of adding the IPs manually, and temporary. First using `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The second is using `ip`:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0
```

note that, unless your secondary IP address is in a completely different network, you don't need to provide the gateway.  And, is also worth noting that your gateway must be on the same network of your interface address.

To have your configuration made permanent you have to create the proper files at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`. The files are named as `ifcfg-eth0:X` where X is the number of the alias.

You may get more info here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-files.html

Comment: According to section 9.2.7 of the RHEL6 manuals, using the "alias" files is no longer considered best practice.  For IPv6, there is a IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES directive that can be added to the base /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* file.  But I'm not sure what the directive is for IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a post on [how to add an IP address / multiple IP's to an interface in CentOS](http://linuxmoz.com/centos-add-ip-address-to-interface).

Hope that helps.